# require_once does not work - in Zend Framework action methods

Tags: php, zend-framework, require-once

I need to integrate Authorize.net payment gateway to my Zf2 application.
Downloaded and copied the PHP SDK in php include path. The sdk has the following files

```
+authoriznet
        +doc
        +lib
            +shared
            +ssl
            -AuthorizeNetSIM.php (and more)
        -AuthorizeNet.php
```

My code (Zend controller) is

```
require_once 'path/AuthorizeNet.php'; /*This require_once AuthorizeNetSIM.php and other files)*/

class PurchaseController extends AbstractActionController{

     public purchaseAction(){
        $works = new AuthorizeNetException("test"); //A class defined in AuthorizeNet.php
        $notFound = new AuthorizeNetSIM;  
     }
}
```

$works -> works fine, where as $notFound throws class not found exception

If i add require_once in view file (.phtml) then all classes in sdk is available to use.

Can someone explain this behaviour? How to properly use this 3rd party library in Zf2?

Comment: Is `AuthorizeNet.php` a file you created, because i dont see it in the [official php sdk](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php). And why are you not simply pushing the autoloadler by using the provided `autoloader.php`? Finally, are you using `composer` or just manually dropping this into your project layout?

Comment: I used composer ("authorizenet/authorizenet": "1.8.0"). After update  the SDK was saved into /vendor/athorizenet folder. And `AuthorizeNet.php` had come with it. There is no `autoloader.php` as in github repo. Following this [guide](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/#hosted)

Comment: Did you try just including the generate composer autoloader like: `require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';` This shoud ensure that anything installed within your project with composer can be autoloaded appropriately.

Comment: I used "authorizenet/authorizenet": "~1.8". This pulled latest SDK (1.8.3) and also the autoloader.php, and rest worked by default without require_once. Thank you